# How does one define C/C++ style macros in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macros

I have noticed that ruby on rails has some small macros that have a c feel.

```
__FILE__ and __LINE__
```

For instance. This makes debugging and generating unique cache keys much easier.

```
store = Rails.cache.fetch("#{__FILE__}|#{__LINE__}|#{self.store_id}")...
```

Most handy when I am likely to get the same store over and over for a given set of orders.

What I'm wondering though is; can I create my own MACROS/defines?  Precompiled code while not a good idea sometimes, does have its place.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to create c style macros in ruby/rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They look like C but they are not macros, they are just objects, like everything else in ruby, these in particular having the power to determine the name and line number of the file currently being interpreted.

C macros are just references to compile-time executable code.  Ruby is ... like, totally, completely opposite from this :-)  Compilation in ruby is really syntax evaluation and then interpretation.  If some languages like C, C++ and Java are early-binding and others like PHP and Python are late-binding, ruby has missed the bus and will get there at the last possible moment.

So if you want to create your own stuff, create a module and/or class having something inside.  What you create inside will be a variable, symbol, constant, or method, perhaps local, of the instance, or of the class, perhaps public, protected or private.  It's generally not good form to use the special naming conventions `__FOO__` or others (even if they are valid names).

(end of answer... if I am hearing what you're asking, perhaps this will help you make the mental leap that is needed)...

I went from C, to C++, to Java, then to Ruby.  After a brief time in the clinic for reformed Java programmers, I was able to understand how amazingly powerful ruby is.  But you really have to think about how to solve problems differently.

I highly recommend the book [Eloquent Ruby, linked here to Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004MMEJ36).

Comment: +1 for encouraging thinking differently. OMG, let's all confess our past transgressions... I'm a reformed BASIC/Assembly/Pascal/C/Java/Perl programmer who's now found the zen-like path of Ruby with occasional lapses in Python. :-) Ruby made me pause and think-different.

Comment: I did dBase, a language which is self-describing in how it makes you feel about yourself.

Comment: I kept quiet about straying into DB2, dBase, rBase and Symphony.

Comment: Reformed, from C?  That doesn't make sense... like getting over being so awe (wait for it) some others weep over their failings.

Answer (score 2):

`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` aren't macros *per se*, they're keywords (that return `String` values).

Having said that, you *are* allowed to define constants and methods that start with an underscore or `_` character. For example:

```
__MICKEY__ = :mouse
```

Now, a constant can refer to anything—a String, an expression, even a code block (a `Proc` or `lambda`) or a whole `Class`.

That means that instead of compile-time macro expansion (Ruby, being an interpreted language, doesn't really have a 'compile phase') you can take advantage of (arguably more powerful) run-time code execution.

For instance, the C++ macro:

```
#define SUM(a, b, c) a + b + c
```

Can be suitably approximated in Ruby as

```
def SUM(a, b, c); a + b + c; end
```

I say 'approximated' because a) in this case we're defining a *method*, not a *constant* or a macro, and b) C++ macros can still work when evaluated with a different number of arguments than they expect (because C++ macros are expanded, meaning, it's as if we did find and replace), whereas Ruby method call semantics come into play, such as checking arity of methods and arguments.

To get around that, in our particular example, we can do (something arguably even more flexible)

```
def SUM(*args); args.inject(:+); end

SUM(1, 2) # => 3
SUM(1, 2, 3, 5) # => 11
```

As you can see, you can achieve a similar (possibly even greater) level of expressiveness that C++ macros provide by leveraging Ruby's dynamic nature.